# C - How to programmatically load a static library in Win32?

Tags: c, windows, dll, static-libraries

I need to be able to switch between a function in a static library and my overridden version in my main app. To do this, I'm trying to use function pointers. The problem is that I don't know how to load a static library into my program. Is this possible? Or do I have to use a DLL?

Comment: The static library is intended to be loaded into your executable during the link stage of the build process.

Comment: If the static library is already linked into your application, you will need to write a facade interface that can switch between using the library's functions or your functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose this might be possible if you have an expert level knowledge of linkers, object file formats, calling conventions, and machine language for your target platform; but static libraries are not intended for this purpose.  Use a DLL.